# Eclipse PDE Plugin - change eclipse settings programmatically

Tags: eclipse, settings, pde, eclipse-api

im working on a eclipse plug-in which deploys a simplified perspective. 
Furthermore i would like to change some eclipse settings. For example i would like to deactivate the Content Assitent when the perspective is loaded.

Is there a possiblity to change these settings programmatically?

Would be nice if someone gives me a litte head start ;)

Thanks Niko